# In Magento, what is an observer exactly? What does it do?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm an extremely novice programmer who finds himself tasked with learning how to program for Magento. So please forgive me for such a rudimentary question but there don't seem to be a ton of beginning level content on Google regarding Mage.

**Can someone explain to me what exactly an observer is? What does it do? What can it be used for?**

If someone can give me a super 101 explanation (not assuming much prior knowledge) you'll be my new hero. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider Event observer as a trigger.
Once you have set an event observer, for example you can set observer `before` or `after` an event, i.e., You can add a event which would execute right after user adds a product to cart or before the add product to cart.

In this event observer, you can write code to customize the data which is either passed to the occuring event **(before)** or is the output of occured event **(after)**

Reference : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

**Event :**

In Magento you may consider a Controller Action as an event, for example **addAction** in **CartController** is an event.

**Observer :**

As mentioned in name, the observer observes when this action occurs (in our case addAction in CartController) and calls a function either before or after this addAction is called.
You may add your custom code in this obeserver for customization.

Comment: Forgive my utter lack of experience, but what constitutes an event?

Comment: Can an event be something simple like a front end user submitting a form? Completing an order? Checking a subscribe-to-newsletter check box? Or is it something more complex...?

Comment: No. it cannot be utilized to observer front end changes like checkbox value.

Actually what you are intended to do with the event observer?

Comment: A few things. We've like to force free shipping on certain orders (w/ a coupon code), but our shipping module is so custom that it refuses to play nicely with the Mage coupon feature (so setting free shipping in the Cart Price Rules in the admin panel does nothing). We've also like to send extra data to our MySQL db when someone click the "subscribe to newsletter" checkbox during checkout. I've been informed by a couple Mage savvy people that I should investigate observers for both of these things...

Answer (score 1):

An Observer is the piece of code you'll need to write if you implement an Event.

Your question is : what is an event ?

See an event as a "broadcast action" that you can intercept in order to add your specific code to a specific action.
There are events fired all over magento key functionnalities.. For example, you can intercept:
- after or before saving a product
- product added to the cart
- etc

It's just an open-door leaved by magento core developers for you to plug-in..

In magento you have several ways to modify the behavior of the standard fucntionnality :
- you can rewrite classes ( tags in config.xml) 
- and you can use the events when an event is available for the functionnality you want to modify

To understand, dive in the code and search "dispatchEvent" in app/code/core ...

Comment: Hi. I found a couple of examples of the dispatchEvent call but I'm having trouble tracing those calls back code in observer files. Any tips?

Comment: The link between Event (fired in the core of magento) and Observer (your specific code) is in the config.xml file of your module (XML node "observers"). Take a look at the links of MageAkash for more details or search for "<observers>" in the magento core directory structure to see how magento does itself